# Is there any way to reload the parent page when close the child page in Fancybox using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using jquery code to reload the parent page, but it is not working for all the child pages. Some pages are getting refreshed while some are not.

I am searching for a pure javascript code to refresh the page when child popup is closed ?

my jquery code is :

```
$(".fancybox-html").fancybox({
    width: '50%',
    height: '50%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    fitToView: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    type: 'iframe',
    afterClose: function () {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: First off, I'm pretty sure you can't use Fancybox without jQuery. I doubt the problem is in your code that refreshes the page if it's working on some pages. I bet on the pages that don't work, you have other JS errors happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @corey .In my child pages iam not using any jquery.

Comment: That's your issue, Fancybox needs jQuery to run.

Comment: `location.reload()` within fancybox callback http://jsfiddle.net/EWTxv/  ... as seen as http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.11

Comment: You cant understand the problem clearly.The parent (parent.html)contains some links (child1.html,chiil2.html,child3.html).When i try to open these child pages all pages are opening perfectly with fancybox effect.but when i close those pages for child 1 and 2 pages the parent page is refreshed.but not for the child3.html

Comment: You can't explain the problem clearly either, this is why people trying to help has no other choice but guessing. What is the code you are using?

Comment: At this point, please post some code.

Comment: fancybox code
$(".fancybox-html").fancybox({ 
width    : '50%', 
height   : '50%', 
autoSize    : false, 
closeClick  : false, 
fitToView   : false, 
openEffect  : 'none', 
closeEffect : 'none', 
type : 'iframe', 
afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});

not working for
<div id="popupID" class="actionset"> 
<button class="fancybox-html" href="addnewset.php">Add New Auction SET</button>

Comment: @chaitanya : edit your question and post your code there (it's quite difficult to read it in the comment area)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Got the answer.
changed in fancybox.js by adding location.reload() to afterclose event.